# Android map search query 'Orchard Road' returns address from Singapore instead of UK

Tags: android, eclipse

Not sure what I need to correct to restrict all results from UK..
Presently query returns results from Singapore instead of UK.
I am using API 19.

```
try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                        Locale.UK);
                List<Address> results = geocoder.getFromLocationName(toSearch,
                        1);

                if (results.size() == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                address = results.get(0);
                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (address.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                        (int) (address.getLongitude() * 1E6));
                MapsActivity.this.myMapController.setCenter(p);
                List<Overlay> mapOverlays = myMapView.getOverlays();
                MapOverlay itemizedoverlay = (MapOverlay) mapOverlays.get(0);
                itemizedoverlay.update(p);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: add UK in your searchQuery

Comment: I think I found the answer (Source Geocoder class reference) :  public List<Address> getFromLocationName (String locationName, int maxResults, double lowerLeftLatitude, double lowerLeftLongitude, double upperRightLatitude, double upperRightLongitude)  You may specify a bounding box for the search results by including the Latitude and Longitude of the Lower Left point and Upper Right point of the box.